# Aggregating data with dimensions in M2M relation

Tags: sql, database, optimization, many-to-many, aggregation

I have a problem with sql query, maybe someone will be able to help me figure it out.

My tables:

**Transaction Table:**

| Field Name | Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| transaction_id | INT |
| amount | FLOAT |
| date | DATETIME |

Each transaction line can have some dimensions assigned. This is a many to many relation, with additional "percentage" field that determines what part of the transaction is marked with dimension

**Dimension Item to Transaction Table (Intermediate Table):**

| Field Name | Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| dimension_item_id | INT |
| transaction_id | INT |
| percentage | FLOAT |

I want to get aggregated data, where value for each combination of dimensions will be a initial amount multiplied by the percentages of the dimensions.

So assuming I have data:

1. Transaction (only one for this example)

| id | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2885776 | 10000 |

2. Dimension

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Dimension 1 |
| 2 | Dimension 2 |
| 3 | Dimension 3 |

3. Dimension Item

| id | dimension_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 57112 | 1 | Item 57112 of dimension 1 |
| 56093 | 1 | Item 56093 of dimension 1 |
| 54232 | 2 | Item 54232 of dimension 2 |
| 54340 | 2 | Item 54340 of dimension 2 |
| 101 | 3 | Item 101 of dimension 3 |

4. DimensionItemToTransaction (M2M intermediate)

| transaction_id | dimension_item_id | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2885776 | 57112 | 50 |
| 2885776 | 57093 | 50 |
| 2885776 | 54232 | 60 |
| 2885776 | 54340 | 40 |
| 2885776 | 101 | 100 |

So in case I have a

- 50-50 split in dimension 1
- 60-40 split in dimension 2
- no split in dimension 3

I meant to achieve this by

1. First getting table like below in a subquery:

| transaction_id | d1 | d1_percentage | d2 | d2_percentage | d3 | d3_percentage | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2885776 | 57112 | 50.00 | 54232 | 60.00 | 101 | 100.00 | 10000 |
| 2885776 | 57112 | 50.00 | 54340 | 40.00 | 101 | 100.00 | 10000 |
| 2885776 | 57093 | 50.00 | 54232 | 60.00 | 101 | 100.00 | 10000 |
| 2885776 | 57093 | 50.00 | 54340 | 40.00 | 101 | 100.00 | 10000 |

2. Then in the main query I can calculate proper amount for each case.

| transaction_id | d1 | d2 | d3 | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2885776 | 57112 | 54232 | 101 | 3000 |
| 2885776 | 57112 | 54340 | 101 | 2000 |
| 2885776 | 57093 | 54232 | 101 | 3000 |
| 2885776 | 57093 | 54340 | 101 | 2000 |

3. Then I can do the rest in Python (grouping by dimensions with proper amount per percentage)

However I am struggling a bit with figuring out the proper way to do that.

I have a query currently that works fine, but it is very slow on larger datasets. In my query for each dimension I want to display I make a separate join on a subquery. This makes this query slow and even slower when I'll add more dimensions to the mix.

First table:

```sql
(  
    SELECT distinct  
       tl.id transaction_id,  

    dimension_1.id as d1,  
    dimension_1.percentage as d1_percentage,  

    dimension_2.id as d2,  
    dimension_2.percentage as d2_percentage,  

    dimension_3.id as d3,  
    dimension_3.percentage as d3_percentage,  

    tl.amount  

    FROM transaction tl  
  
  
left join (  
    select dtt.transaction_id, dtt.percentage percentage, dtt.dimension_item_id, od.id as id  
        from dimensionitemtotransaction dtt  
        join dimensionitem od on dtt.dimension_item_id = od.id  
        where od.dimension_id = 1  
    ) dimension_1 on tl.id = dimension_1.transaction_id  
  
left join (  
    select dtt.transaction_id, dtt.percentage percentage, dtt.dimension_item_id, od.id as id  
        from dimensionitemtotransaction dtt  
        join dimensionitem od on dtt.dimension_item_id = od.id  
        where od.dimension_id = 2  
    ) dimension_2 on tl.id = dimension_2.transaction_id  
  
left join (  
    select dtt.transaction_id, dtt.percentage percentage, dtt.dimension_item_id, od.id as id  
        from dimensionitemtotransaction dtt  
        join dimensionitem od on dtt.dimension_item_id = od.id  
        where od.dimension_id = 3  
    ) dimension_3 on tl.id = dimension_3.transaction_id  
  
) sq
```

Second table:

```sql
select distinct  
 transaction_id, d1, d2, d3,

coalesce(sum(  
    amount * coalesce(d1_percentage, 100) / 100 * coalesce(d2_percentage, 100) / 100 * coalesce(d3_percentage, 100) / 100  
), 0.0) as amount

from
    ( above subquery here ) sq

group by transaction_id, d1, d2, d3;
```

All my foreign keys are indexed.

I feel that this is a bad way to do that, but I'm having difficulties figuring any other way and I would appreciate suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi - please update your question to show sample data for your source tables and the result you want to achieve, based on that data

Comment: Sure! I added the source tables data. Thank you for your time.